# How to get friends of a user's friends with Tweepy/TwitterAPI without putting too much load on the rate limit?

Tags: tweepy, rate-limiting, twitterapi-python

I am using the tweepy API, and I made a method that gets who a user's following (aka Friends).

```
    def get_following(self, name=''):
        client = self.twitter_client
        following_results = tweepy.Cursor(client.friends, screen_name=name, count=200).pages()
        i = 0
        # Each page returns a list of what you requested (in this case: users).
        for list_of_users in following_results:
            for user in list_of_users:
                 # do something with the user
```

I am trying to build a simple program that will get friends of a user's friends.

input a user -> retrieve friends of that user -> **for each friend of input user get a list of their friends** (end goal).

Writing the logic to get this data isn't an issue.

I am having a big issue with the rate limit. With the first user that you input into the method it's fine. I tested the method above on a user with 500 friends and using the tweepy rate_limit_status(), the 15 requests for friends went down by 3 to 12 requests as expected (200 max count, so 3 times pagination), but with that rate, assuming this user's next four friends also have 500 followers, I can only request five users per 15 minutes (that's including the inputted user in the first iteration). So assuming every friend of this user ALSO has 500 friends (unlikely could be more), it will take one hundred (5 requests/15 minute sessions * 100 = all 500 of the original user's friends) 15 minute sessions to get all of the friends of the original user's friends (25 hours).

This is a long amount of time, and I checked Stack overflow and tweepy/twitter API documentation to solve this dilemma, and I haven't really found anything so I might as well ask here. I was trying to make this an easy use program in which any username can just be typed, and I get the output of the friends of the user's friends, but this is already a challenge time-wise for a single user.

Is this even possible with the current Twitter Rate limit of 15 friend requests/15 minutes or is there a way around this?

Thanks.